# How to select the rows based on the the date field which are in last 7 days before today's date in Arcgis Pro

Tags: arcgis

I am using the Select by attribute tool to select the records in Arcgis Pro. I have a date field name T: (A 1305) Site Walk-Finish so I need to select only those records which has the date (T: (A 1305) Site Walk-Finish) which are in last 7 days of today's date. I am not sure how to write the expression.

[image: Select by attribute]

Comment: I think ArcGIS Pro questions are far more on-topic at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pretty good run-down of some queries you can paste into that box:

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm#GUID-85C03D85-F4A5-48FC-8E8C-3F79919430DB